# how to wait for lambda expression finish

Tags: java, android, lambda

I have a problem with lambda expression; I used lambda expression in return type method but `return isDownloaded.get()` execute before lambda expression . how I can wait for lambda finish?

```
 public  boolean isDowloaded(int id) {

AtomicReference<Boolean> isdownload = new AtomicReference<>(false);
AtomicReference<List<Download>> downloadList = new AtomicReference<>();

MyApplication.getInstance().getFetch().getDownloads(downloads -> {

    downloadList.set(downloads);
    for (int i = 0; i < downloadList.get().size(); i++) {
        if (downloadList.get().get(i).getExtras().getString("id","").equals(String.valueOf(id)) ) {
            PlayerConstants.SONG_NUM = i;
            isdownload.set(true);
        }
    }


});

        // always return false in this case
return isdownload.get();
```

}

Comment: what do you mean wait for lambda to finish? `downloads -> {...}` would execute always before `isdownload.get()`.

Comment: Are you sure `isdownload.set(true);` is reached?

Comment: @Naman no `downloads ->{...}` extract data from database and probably write in async task (belong to external library "Fetch")

Comment: @Guy Yes. but after `return isdownload.get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda is not the problem there.
The `getDownloads()` call is asynchronous.  So the `isDowloaded()` method that invokes that should not return a `boolean` since it doesn't know when the processing will be finished.
It should be a `void` method. One of the main `Fetch` api feature is 
downloading in the background.

So you have to implement a callback to perform a post processing.

2 possibilities :

- implement and add a [`FetchListener`](https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch).
- perform the post processing after the return of the asynchronous call.

For example :

```
MyApplication.getInstance().getFetch().getDownloads(downloads -> {

    downloadList.set(downloads);
    for (int i = 0; i < downloadList.get().size(); i++) {
       //...
    }
    // ... DO your post processing here

});
```

Comment: I used interface and passing boolean to it and it works. but your answer guide me . thank you